# Construct string slice from vector of string slices

Tags: rust

I have a vector holding `n` string slices. I would like to construct a string slice based on these.

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<&str> = vec!["foo", "bar"];
    let h: &str = "home";

    let result = format!("hello={}@{}&{}@{}", v[0], h, v[1], h);

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

I searched through the docs but I failed to find anything on this subject.

Comment: So, what's the problem?  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=590c0bae000aa89006b23a5b3fe89884

Comment: @eggyal The problem is that I don't want to manually do this `n` times by indexing the vector.

Comment: Because [`String` implements `FromIterator<&str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-FromIterator%3C%26%27a%20str%3E), you can simply [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) an iterator: `v.iter().collect::<String>()`

Comment: @eggyal Sorry I don't see how this concatenates `n` slices into a customisable slice as shown in the question.

Comment: No problem.  Your question wasn't very clear that that was a requirement (indeed it wasn't even clear that you were seeking a solution for an arbitrary length vector).  This clarification has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done (somewhat inefficiently) with iterators:

```
let result = format!("hello={}",
    v.iter().map(|s| format!("{}@{}", s, h))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join("&")
);
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e2cabb3307f93afca58b767172e0522d))

If high performance is needed, a loop that builds a `String` will be quite a bit faster.  The approach above allocates an additional `String` for each input `&str`, then a vector to hold them all before finally joining them together.

---

Here's a more efficient way to implement this.  The operation carried out by this function is to call the passed function for each element in the iterator, giving it access to the `std::fmt::Write` reference passed in, and sticking the iterator in between successive calls.  (Note that `String` implements `std::fmt::Write`!)

```
use std::fmt::Write;

fn delimited_write<W, I, V, F>(writer: &mut W, seq: I, delim: &str, mut func: F)
    -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error>
    where W: Write,
        I: IntoIterator<Item=V>,
        F: FnMut(&mut W, V) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error>
{
    let mut iter = seq.into_iter();
    
    match iter.next() {
        None => { },
        Some(v) => {
            func(writer, v)?;
    
            for v in iter {
                writer.write_str(delim)?;
                func(writer, v)?;
            }
        },
    };
    
    Ok(())
}
```

You'd use it to implement your operation like so:

```
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<&str> = vec!["foo", "bar"];
    let h: &str = "home";
    
    let mut result: String = "hello=".to_string();
    
    delimited_write(&mut result, v.iter(), "&", |w, i| {
        write!(w, "{}@{}", i, h)
    }).expect("write succeeded");
    
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

It's not as pretty, but it makes no temporary String or Vec allocations. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=36e354a785aef21171fe2444d843c622))

Comment: Thank you for both explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You will *need* to iterate over the vector as cdhowie suggests above. Let me explain why this is necessarily an `O(n)` problem and you can't create a single string slice from a vector of string slices without iterating over the vector:

Your vector only holds references to the strings; it doesn't hold the strings themselves. The strings are likely not stored contiguously in memory (only their *references* inside your vector are) so combining them into a single slice is not as simple as creating a slice that points to the beginning of the first string referenced in the vector and then extending the size of the slice.

Given that a `&str` is just an integer indicating the length of the slice and a pointer to a location in memory or the application binary where a `str` (essentially an array of `char`'s) is stored, you can imagine that if the first `&str` in your vector references a string on the stack and the next one references a hardcoded string that is stored in the executable binary of the program, there is no way to create a single `&str` that points to both `str`'s without copying at least one of them (in practice, probably both of them will be copied).

In order to get a single string slice from all of those `&str`'s in your vector, you need to copy each of the `str`'s they reference to a single, contiguous chunk of memory and then create a slice of that chunk. That copying requires iterating over the vector.